# Derivative of $g(t) = Df(x + t(y-x))(y - x)$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $x$ represents the column vector while $x^T$ represents horizontal vector.

I was told that $g'(t) = (y - x)^T D^2f(x + t(y - x))(y - x)$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORRECT VERSION
$g'(t) = \frac d {dt} g(t)$. Therefore we need to take the derivative of the right side of the original equation with respect to $t$. And therefore in this sense $(y-x)$ is just some constant.

Using the chain rule, $$ \frac d {dt} (Df(x+t(y-x))) = \frac {d(Df)} {d(x+t(y-x))} \frac {d(x+t(y-x))} {dt} $$, and remember that $x$ and $y-x$ is just some constant, which gives $$D^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$$.

And now we add the constant part to the mix - take the dot product.
$$(D^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)) \cdot (y-x)$$

Which is the same as $$ \frac d {dt} (Df(x+t(y-x))(y-x)) = (y-x)^TD^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x) $$.